# My /boot partition broke. How do I write everything needed there?

Tags: debian, boot, system-installation, boot-loader

I use debian 9. For some reason the partition where my `/boot` lies is broken, `e2fsck` reported many errors. Somehow I am still able to boot into emergency mode. I can format that partition. How do I write everything needed (grub, kernel, etc.) there again?

Comment: Use debian installation media to boot into recovery mode, then chroot to your installed system. You can then reformat&reinstall (kernel and grub) to your boot partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have luck, everything in `/boot` can be easily reproduced automatically.

1. Boot into rescue mode.
2. Unmount /boot (if it is mounted - it is possible, that it can't be mounted. The command is: `umount /boot`)
3. Fix your `/boot` filesystem. If it is ext2-3-4, then the command: `e2fsck -f -y -C0 /dev/your-boot-partition`. These are very agressive, enforcing-destructive flags, but you don't have to be very careful with the data on it - all of it is reporducible automatically. And, if it runs without a problem, you can be sure, that finally your `/boot` filesystem will be okay.
4. *If the e2fsck output didn't say any terrible (P > 90%), then your /boot is probably already fixed, and you can reboot. But if not, then you can have an unbootable system.*
5. Mount the partition again (`mount /boot`)
6. Check, which packages installed anything into `/boot`. This can be done by the command `dpkg -S /boot`. In my case, the result is this:

---

```
# dpkg -S /boot
linux-image-4.4.0-38-lowlatency, memtest86+, grub2-theme-mint, memtest86, linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic, base-files: /boot
```

Then, you can simply reinstall these packages by the command

```
apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-4.4.0-38-lowlatency memtest86+ grub2-theme-mint memtest86 linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic base-files
```

There are also various boot and config files there, but the (re)install script of these packages will automatically re-construct them all.

---

It should be enough, but if you want to be very, very sure, you can also regenerate the boot files again, by hand, with the commands

```
update-grub
```

...and reinstall grub to the MBR by

```
grub-install /dev/your-boot-disk (most probably /dev/sda)
```

---

In the - improbable - case that something would go wrong and your system becomes unbootable, you can do nearly the same steps from a rescue CD/pendrive. The details are in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) answer.

---

Extension: after all, you may check the files restored by the `e2fsck` in `/boot/lost+found`. You don't need them, because all the data in them are already reproduced. To save place on the (typically, small) boot partition, you may delete them.

Comment: I did this with chroot from a liveusb, because otherwise my internet connection woudln't work because of missing firmware. It worked thanks.